# How to protect the SMS registration service from an attack with bulk sms sending?

Tags: security, sms

There is a registration service using SMS. The phone number is transmitted to the api of the service, then the service sends the code in SMS. How to protect the service from an attack using bulk SMS. For example, an attacker will send multiple API requests with different random phone numbers. It is possible to identify attempts to register by IP. But the provider can use one IP for a large number of users.

It is possible to limit the number of hits from one IP per minute.

Answer (score 0):

you can add rate limit, doesn't it work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).